# How to modify default lib linkage for Android cross toolchain (linking without libc++ and libm)

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, dynamic-linking

I have built a small Android system that uses less memory for my native apps.

I found that all my apps will link to `libm.so` and `libstdc++.so` even though they were written purely in C and do not use any functions in `libm` (e.g `sin()`). The lib uses over 20K of memory.

How can I remove the linkages of `libstdc++` and `libm`?

Answer (score 1):

Without dismissing your goal in principle, Android launches apps via forking off a child from the zygote process which has preloaded lots of system libraries into memory for shared usage by all apps.  Many dalvik classes are also preloaded.

Since you inherit these shared mappings, there's actually very little physical memory consumed - for each child process in which an application runs, the preload libraries and classes only consume memory for tracking data on the preloaded code space, and for writable data space.

Due to this, it actually saves memory to give all apps something which only a majority would need, rather than to have the ones that need it load their own (unsharable) copy.   Also, while a developer written ndk library might use only C, an android app as a whole is unavoidably a C++ program due to included pieces of platform code.

Comment: +1.. on top of what you mention, dalvik is surely already linked with libm and libstdc++, so they'll already be mapped in the process the ndk library is loaded into (even if nothing else used 'em). I've removed my pointless answer :-)